# Minor correction of In Press article

Tags: publications, publishers

I noticed an obvious minor mistake in an in-press article. It is related to the description of symbols in an equation, but it does not alter the rest of the manuscript in any way (they were used properly in the rest of the manuscript). Also, any attentive reader could note (and fix) it.

Should I contact to the editor or what to do?

---

EDIT: I also thought in contact directly to the editorial team due to the smallness of the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your article is in press, don't contact the editorial board. Their role of handling peer review is over. What's left is for the publisher to publish the paper, and they're the ones who can fix this. You can fix this, and any other minor issues you find, when you receive the proofs from the publisher.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already received the proof, but I did not notice up to right now.

Comment: @user1420303 if you've already resubmitted the proofs, tell the editorial team quickly - the later it goes, the more likely the paper reaches a point where it's very inconvenient to make changes. Otherwise, just make the change as you resubmit the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, contact the editor. Everyone has an interest in getting things right. Whether it is possible or not at a late stage is up to them, but offer the correction and do it soon. Apologize.